Switch to master auto position from master_log_file and master_log_pos MySQL 5.7.44
MySQL Server - 5.7.44
I have a master and three slaves running on MySQL 5.7.44.
The GTID is enabled and I am using gtid_enforce_consistency.
I took a backup from a slave and built a fourth slave using xtrabackup. Following is the command I used to backup the data.
xtrabackup --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --user="bkp_user" --password="password" --port=3306 --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --backup --use-memory=2048MB --tmpdir=/tmp/

after copying the backup to the data directory, I applied the logs
xtrabackup --apply-log --use-memory=10G . 

and then once the logs are applied, after changing the ownership of the files, I started the new slave. I added skip-slave-start in the config file before starting the new slave.
I, then, used the following command to connect the slave to the server from where I had taken backup.
change master to master_host='IP', MASTER_USER='replica', MASTER_PASSWORD='password', MASTER_AUTO_POSITION=1;

I kept receiving the Duplicate entry errors 1062. I skipped one GTID and started the replication, but it kept happening and I kept receiving 1062 error.
LAST_ERROR_MESSAGE: Worker 1 failed executing transaction '8e36a7e9-4bb6-11ea-9989-0aab56f5ae8e:4967477654' at master log binlog.000454, end_log_pos 638; Could not execute Write_rows event on table db.table; Duplicate entry '97193728' for key 'PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the event's master log FIRST, end_log_pos 638
 LAST_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 2024-11-22 22:38:18

I had to switch back to BINLOG POSITION based replication.
STOP SLAVE;
RESET SLAVE ALL;
change master to master_host='IP', MASTER_USER='replica', MASTER_PASSWORD='password', MASTER_LOG_FILE='binlog.000454', MASTER_LOG_POS=772253840;

And replication is working fine. I am out of thought, what did I miss? Also how do I safely switch back to MASTER_AUTO_POSITION?
This link gives a simple procedure to do so, but really not sure and haven't tried it yet
https://thedataguy.in/mysql-convert-binlog-based-replication-to-gtid-replication-without-downtime/
This percona blog talks about doing that on MariaDB, reading, searching further
https://www.percona.com/blog/convert-mariadb-binary-log-file-and-position-based-replication-to-gtid-replication/

Something like this is simpler:  Stop one rejplica; clone its disk start replica; change the new replica's server_id; start replica.  (Reset and Change Master scare me.)

I will have to try that, but why reset and change master is scary? @RickJames

Replication must be started at the place where it left off.  Both RESET and CHANGE alter that; blindly applied will lead to a mess on the Replica.  Carefully applied, one and/or the other may achieve your goal.  I do not have experience with GTID, which adds another dimension to the issue.

yes, so I can make the slave single threaded, let it catch up for a minute or two, stop slave, record the position, reset master, change master and start. then I can enable mtr.
